# Validations in filter class

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

For my web application I have written `AuthenticationFilter` which validates each request to check against CSRF attacks, Browser Checks, Session Validity etc. Instead of putting multiple if else blocks I thought it can be implemented as following.

Please let me know if I can improve this.

```
public interface IValidator {

    public void validate(Context context) throws ValidatorException;

    public void handleFailure(Context context) throws Exception;

}

public class CSRFValidator implements IValidator, CWSConstants {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSRFValidator.class);

    @Override
    public void validate(Context context) throws ValidatorException {
        //some logic to validate request if it contains CSRF token
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFailure(Context context) throws Exception {
        context.getHttpServletResponse().sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION);
    }
}

public class BrowserCheckValidator implements IValidator, CWSConstants {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSRFValidator.class);

    @Override
    public void validate(Context context) throws ValidatorException {
        //if request is not coming from suported browser then throw exception
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFailure(Context context) throws Exception {
        context.getHttpServletResponse().sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION);
    }
}

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter{
    private List<IValidator> requestValidators = new ArrayList<>();

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain fc)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
                            Context context = new Context(httpRequest, httpResponse, session);
        for (IValidator validator : requestValidators) {
            try {
                LOGGER.debug("Validating " + validator.getClass().getName());
                validator.validate(context);
            } catch (ValidatorException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error while validating " + validator.getClass().getName(), e);
                validator.handleFailure(context);
                return;
            }
        }
        fc.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        LOGGER.debug("Initializing validators");
        requestValidators.add(new CSRFValidator());
    }

}
public class ValidatorException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8990146478624920065L;

    public ValidatorException() {
        super();
    }

    public ValidatorException(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }

    public ValidatorException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public ValidatorException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ValidatorException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

public final class Context {

    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
    private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    public Context(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            HttpSession httpSession) {
        this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
        this.httpServletResponse = httpServletResponse;
        this.httpSession = httpSession;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getHttpServletRequest() {
        return httpServletRequest;
    }

    public HttpServletResponse getHttpServletResponse() {
        return httpServletResponse;
    }

    public HttpSession getHttpSession() {
        return httpSession;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "Please let me know if I can go ahead with this" as code review is about improving a written code not asking if you code is syntactically correct. Use words like "Can this be Improved"

Comment: Except that *C++* style `IValidator` interface name, it looks fine for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instead of putting multiple if else blocks I thought it can be implemented as following.

Looks like the *Strategy Pattern* with polymorphic dispatch.
A sound plan!

#### Make fields `final` when possible

The private fields of `Context` can all be `final`.
It's good to make them `final` so you won't change them by accident.
`final` fields are easier to read, as you *know* they will only ever have the same value.

#### Avoid throwing `Exception`

`IValidator.handleFailure` is defined with `throws Exception`.
It's recommended to avoid using the generic `Exception` class,
it's better to use specific exceptions.
Code using this interface is forced to catch `Exception`,
which creates the risk that other exception types may be caught by mistake.

#### Implement just what you need

Do you need all the constructors in `ValidatorException`?
In the posted code, there isn't a single use case using of any of those.
I suggest to implement only the functionality you actually need,
and avoid to implement in advance something "you might need someday".

#### Conventions

In Java it's not a convention to prefix interface names with a capital `I`.
I suggest to rename `IValidator` to `Validator`.

#### The constant interface antipattern

You haven't shared the code of `CWSConstants`,
but it sounds like it might simply contain constants,
and your classes implement this interface only to have easy access to those constants.

This is considered a bad practice. Interfaces are intended for contracts of behaviors, using them for easy access of constants is an abuse of the language. The alternative is to put the constants in a class instead of an interface. You may use static imports to avoid polluting the code with the name of the class everywhere.